# how use ffmpeg to convert caf file?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

I am using a ffmpeg to convert audio files. It is used for voice login mechanism for my web application. The problem occurs when I am using it from IOS application, but it works for web. IOS application is sending aa audio file to api, and it is converted on server side. Server is running script:

```
ffmpeg -i $1 -ar 8000 -ac 1 $2
```

$1 and $2 is input and output file path respectively. The only difference is file format as IOS is using .caf instead of .wav. When I run application for .caf file I have following error:

```
/app/tmp/voices/1448448813_sample.caf: Input/output error
```

It is a ffmpeg problem? How to fix it?

Comment: Please provide a sample input file so the issue can be duplicated, and show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: do you have a sample caf file?